# .NET Como pasar codigo inyectado a una libreria de clases

Tags: .net, class, inyeccion-de-dependencias

No sé si estoy haciendo algo imposible, pero allá va.

En mi ASP.NET v7 tengo un applicationsettings.json con unos valores. Esos valores los mapeo a una clase a través de la instrucción `builder.Services.Configure<ConfiguracionCMS>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConfiguracionCMS"));` por lo que en Index.cshtml.cs puedo hacer esto:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IOptions<ConfiguracionCMS> _conf;

        public IndexModel(IOptions<ConfiguracionCMS> conf)
        {
            _conf = conf;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
```

Ese `conf` tiene configuraciones necesarias para otra clase (Archivo.cs) (que tiene un constructor vacío y otro que rellena los datos de una BD) en otro proyecto (librería de clases)

Así que en el método `OnGet()` de Index.cshtml.cs puedo hacer `new Archivo(id)` y obtener un archivo con ese ID, pero necesita si o si el `conf` si no no sabe donde buscarlo.

No quiero tener que pasar siempre el `conf` y he supuesto que habrá alguna manera de que DI lo inyecte también en la librería, pero no veo como.

No sé si tengo que cambiar los constructores de la librería, la llamada o ambos o ninguno... ¡No sé!

He probado a crear un constructor con solo la configuración y le llamo desde otros constructores, a añadir parámetros de configuración a otros constructores....

Comment: Saludos. Simplificar y procesos queden en un solo lugar es idóneo al codificar; principalmente para cambiar un solo lugar se se aplique a todo. si el `conf` es el mismo para todo código (o hay alguna forma de diferenciarlo cualq cargar) es esa parte que debes crear donde se inicialice; una clase adicional que lo contenga y retorne ya con los datos para solo usarlo es lo que debes hacer y `IOptions<ConfiguracionCMS> _conf` seria (digamos) `NuevaClase conf`, aún así necesitaras invocar el constructor (que definas) para que todo se inicialice.

Comment: Gracias RobertoLeOr.
Tengo algo con clases estáticas que me funciona, pero quería algo con DI, para entender como funciona todo esto